# Writing a tic tac toe program

Tags: python, list

```
board_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
row1 = [1, 2, 3]
row2 = [4, 5, 6]
row3 = [7, 8, 9]
board_list = [row1, row2, row3]

divider = 10*'-'
print(board_list [0][0],'|',board_list [0][1],'|',board_list [0][2])
print(divider)
print(board_list [1][0],'|',board_list [1][1],'|',board_list [1][2])
print(divider)
print(board_list [2][0],'|',board_list [2][1],'|',board_list [2][2])
                                                                                                     
move_list = (input('Enter the move string:')).split(' ')
```

im trying to write a simple tic tac toe program. Im think I figured out the way to make the board but now I have to access the board to replace each spot with a X or a O. Im new to coding and this has my mind blown. Any tips or idea to get this working? thanks.

Comment: See here for ideas on a Tic Tac Toe game: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65729757/5237560

Comment: Writing a tic tac toe program is not a trivial task and certainly not an exercise for someone new to coding.  It requires an understanding of certain algorithms such as the Monte Carlo algorithm or the minimax recursive algorithm.  Are you just tryring to draw the tic tac toe board?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as simple as `x = 0`

what you want to do is overwrite the value of a variable, in your case you have created a nested list of values to represent the board.
You already know how to access a nested value - for example to access top left symbol on your board you want to access `board_list[0][0]` and for the center piece `board_list[1][1]`.

To overwrite the value simply run `board_list[x][y] = z` where `z` is the new value

I reformatted your code a little bit to run a full working example, here a user inputs space-separated indices of a field to be replaced with `'X'`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#packed everything into functions to avoid rewriting the same pieces of code

def create_board():
    row1 = [1, 2, 3]
    row2 = [4, 5, 6]
    row3 = [7, 8, 9]
    board_list = [row1, row2, row3]
    return board_list

def show_board(board):
    divider = 10*'-'
    for row in board:
        if row != board[0]:
            print(divider)
        print(row[0],'|',row[1],'|',row[2])

def main():
    board = create_board()
    show_board(board)
    move = (input('Enter the move string [x y]:')).split(' ')
    row = int(move[0])
    column = int(move[1])
    board[row][column] = 'X'
    show_board(board)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```