# Tic Tac Toe against computer (python): code seems redundant

Tags: python

I wrote a code that is a Tic Tac Toe game against a computer opponent. It's functional but clunky. Does anyone have any suggestions of how to make it more succinct? I had to do a lot of repetitive lines that I'm sure could've been solved in an easier way. Thanks so much for any help. The code:

```
import random

outcome = False

#Print the board

theBoard = {'top L': '', 'top M': '', 'top R':'', 'mid L': '', 'mid M': '', 'mid R': '', 'low L':'', 'low M':'', 'low R':''}

print(theBoard['top L'] + ' | ' + theBoard['top M'] + ' | ' + theBoard['top R'])
print('------')
print(theBoard['mid L'] + ' | ' + theBoard['mid M'] + ' | ' + theBoard['mid R'])
print('------')
print(theBoard['low L'] + ' | ' + theBoard['low M'] + ' | ' + theBoard['low R'])

# Game loop

while outcome == False:
    print('Your move:')
    playerMove = input()


    if playerMove == 'top L':
        theBoard['top L'] = 'X'
    elif playerMove == 'top M':
        theBoard['top M'] = 'X'
    elif playerMove == 'top R':
        theBoard['top R'] = 'X'
    elif playerMove == 'mid L':
        theBoard['mid L'] = 'X'
    elif playerMove == 'mid M':
        theBoard['mid M'] = 'X'
    elif playerMove == 'mid R':
        theBoard['mid R'] = 'X'
    elif playerMove == 'low L':
        theBoard['low L'] = 'X'
    elif playerMove == 'low M':
        theBoard['low M'] = 'X'
    elif playerMove == 'low R':
        theBoard['low R'] = 'X'
    else:
        print('That is not a space.')

    # Print the board

    print(theBoard['top L'] + ' | ' + theBoard['top M'] + ' | ' + theBoard['top R'])
    print('------')
    print(theBoard['mid L'] + ' | ' + theBoard['mid M'] + ' | ' + theBoard['mid R'])
    print('------')
    print(theBoard['low L'] + ' | ' + theBoard['low M'] + ' | ' + theBoard['low R'])

    

    # Computer move

    print('My turn.')
    while True:
        computerMove = random.randint(1,10)
        if computerMove == 1 and theBoard['top L'] == '':
            theBoard['top L'] = 'O'
            break
        elif computerMove == 1 and theBoard['top L'] != '':
            continue
        elif computerMove == 2 and theBoard['top M'] == '':
            theBoard['top M'] = 'O'
            break
        elif computerMove == 2 and theBoard['top M'] != '':
            continue
        elif computerMove == 3 and theBoard['top R'] == '':
            theBoard['top R'] = 'O'
            break
        elif computerMove == 3 and theBoard['top R'] != '':
            continue
        elif computerMove == 4 and theBoard['mid L'] == '':
            theBoard['mid L'] = 'O'
            break
        elif computerMove == 4 and theBoard['mid L'] != '':
            continue
        elif computerMove == 5 and theBoard['mid M'] == '':
            theBoard['mid M'] = 'O'
            break
        elif computerMove == 5 and theBoard['mid M'] != '':
            continue
        elif computerMove == 6 and theBoard['mid R'] == '':
            theBoard['mid R'] = 'O'
            break
        elif computerMove == 6 and theBoard['mid R'] != '':
            continue
        elif computerMove == 7 and theBoard['low L'] == '':
            theBoard['low L'] = 'O'
            break
        elif computerMove == 7 and theBoard['low L'] != '':
            continue
        elif computerMove == 8 and theBoard['low M'] == '':
            theBoard['low M'] = 'O'
            break
        elif computerMove == 8 and theBoard['low M'] != '':
            continue
        elif computerMove == 9 and theBoard['low R'] == '':
            theBoard['low R'] = 'O'
            break
        elif computerMove == 9 and theBoard['low R'] != '':
            continue
        
    # Print board again
            
    print(theBoard['top L'] + ' | ' + theBoard['top M'] + ' | ' + theBoard['top R'])
    print('------')
    print(theBoard['mid L'] + ' | ' + theBoard['mid M'] + ' | ' + theBoard['mid R'])
    print('------')
    print(theBoard['low L'] + ' | ' + theBoard['low M'] + ' | ' + theBoard['low R'])

            

    
    # Check to see if there are 3 in a row
    
    if theBoard['top L'] != ('') and theBoard['top L'] == theBoard['top M'] == theBoard['top R']:
        print('Winner!')
        break
    elif theBoard['mid L'] != ('') and theBoard['mid L'] == theBoard['mid M'] == theBoard['mid R']:
        print('Winner!')
        break
    elif theBoard['low L'] != ('') and theBoard['low L'] == theBoard['low M'] == theBoard['low R']:
        print('Winner!')
        break
    elif theBoard['top M'] != ('') and theBoard['top M'] == theBoard['mid M'] == theBoard['low M']:
        print('Winner!')
        break
    elif theBoard['top R'] != ('') and theBoard['top R'] == theBoard['mid R'] == theBoard['low R']:
        print('Winner!')
        break
    elif theBoard['top R'] != ('') and theBoard['top R'] == theBoard['mid M'] == theBoard['low L']:
        print('Winner!')
        break
    elif theBoard['top L'] != ('') and theBoard['top L'] == theBoard['mid M'] == theBoard['low R']:
        print('Winner!')
        break
    elif theBoard['top L'] != ('') and theBoard['top L'] == theBoard['mid L'] == theBoard['low L']:
        print('Winner!')
        break
```

Thanks for any help because I'm still very new to this!

Comment: For code that is working where you desire refactoring, there is a stackexchange site https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ that would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I think that if you don't end up getting help on here, it might be worth also posting to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - this might be more up their alley. They have specific guidelines for posting that you need to look up, but otherwise if this code works then I think it's eligible for posting on there.

Comment: Incidentally your instincts are right: there are quite a lot of ways to get this less clunky, and wanting to cut down on repetition is a sound instinct (not answering here because it's off topic, but looks on topic for code review). But well done on getting it working :)

Comment: You would need to change your data representation of the board to leverage numerical indexing.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65729757/5237560) for an example using a simple 9-element list:

Answer (score 0):

**try using functions and lists**

```
import random


theBoard = {'top L': '', 'top M': '', 'top R':'', 'mid L': '', 'mid M': '', 'mid R': '', 'low L':'', 'low M':'', 'low R':''}


def write_board():
    print(theBoard['top L'] + ' | ' + theBoard['top M'] + ' | ' + theBoard['top R'])
    print('------')
    print(theBoard['mid L'] + ' | ' + theBoard['mid M'] + ' | ' + theBoard['mid R'])
    print('------')
    print(theBoard['low L'] + ' | ' + theBoard['low M'] + ' | ' + theBoard['low R'])


def control_state(point_list):
    if random_list == []:
        print("===========")
        print("Sorry There is No Move :(")
        print("===========")
        return True
        
    if len(point_list) > 2:
        for ws in winner_states:            
            counter = 0
            for p in point_list:
                if p in ws:
                    counter += 1
            if counter == 3:
                print("===========")
                write_board()
                print("===========")
                print("Winner")
                return True
    return False


random_list = [i for i in range(1,10)]
winner_states = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [1,5,9], [3,5,7], [1,4,7], [2,5,8], [3,6,9]]
player_state = []
pc_state = []
finish = False


# Game loop
while True:

    write_board()
    print('Your move:')    
    playerMove = input()

    if playerMove in theBoard:
        if theBoard[playerMove] == "":
            theBoard[playerMove] = "X"
            no = list(theBoard.keys()).index(playerMove)+1
            player_state.append(no)
            random_list.remove(no)
            
            if control_state(player_state):
                break
        else:
            print("wrong move !")
            continue
    else:
        print("wrong move !")
        continue

    #your move
    write_board()
    

    # Computer move
    print('My turn.')

    while True:        
        rnd = random.choice(random_list)
        random_list.remove(rnd)
        pc_move = list(theBoard.keys())[rnd-1]

        if theBoard[pc_move] == "":
            theBoard[pc_move] = "0"
            pc_state.append(rnd)
            break
    
    if control_state(pc_state):
        break
```